# Does iOS iCloud Drive Files get deleted from the device to free space?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, space

I'm using Just Press Record on iOS 10.11.1. Since it records audio and keeps a synchronized transcription of the recordings, I'd like to keep all my recordings there. The app keeps the files in its own folder on iCloud Drive. I have an iPhone with 16GB of storage and the recordings will eventually be a lot.

**The question**: Does iOS "delete" iCloud Drive Files from the device while keeping a version online when the device has low free space (like macOS Sierra does)?